# How to use SQLite with libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I was wondering if anyone knows a good tutorial that explains how to use SQLite with libgdx. All the ones I have found don't explain it well and I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it. So if you know of one that explains everything decently please give me the link to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Libgdx backends are you interested in?  What specifically is your problem?  Do you not know how to setup the SQLite connection in Java/Libgdx?  Or are you not sure how to use SQLite itself?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the extensions available won't work for multi-platform, at max you'll be able to support Android and Desktop. My advise is for you to create your own classes for methods for accessing info stored as files on the device trough the LibGDX File API. You won't get to use SQL and it will certainly take longer but you'll get try multi-platform support (if that is what you're looking too of course).

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/SQLite

Try this, although it is rather a suggestion of implementation rather than a full blown tutorial.

Comment: I have read this many times but I don't understand what it is having me do.

Comment: The resolver classes provide you with JDBC drivers in which you can use JDBC calls similar to the examples provided here...

http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/

Comment: Alright I read through the jdbc tutorial and it explained a lot thank you. But now I'm having trouble understanding a few things. One is how is the code shown in the libgdx wiki used? All I can think of is once you start the app you call one of the resolvers depending on what the user is using (either desktop or android) but once you do that what would I do? Also another thing I'm having trouble with is for android how would I recreate the database based on a sqlite dump? And for desktop users where do I put the database at to access it?

Comment: It's been awhile, but from what I understand you various entry points for your Android/Desktop/html5 libgdx project... maybe if you built a wrapper around the resolvers or whatever, then you wouldnt have to worry about inconsistencies between the location of  the DB (for android it would be different then desktop).

On the desktop you would simply create the database on your harddrive..

Answer (score 1):

A Libgdx user proposed an SQLite extension several months ago.  Its definitely a work-in-progress, but might be a good place to get some ideas or borrow some code from: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/222

Comment: The extension has already been completed and is located at: https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite