# Creating a dialogue in Java with libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to make a dialogue tree (conversation tree) in Java using libGDX. Should I use lots of conditionals (if,else etc...) and move on to the next dialogue or is there a better way to read a file such as XML that already have the dialogues inside? Also, I want the solution that would consume the least possible memory amount because I am going to write it for Android.

Example of the dialogue tree:

(Q: Question, A: Answer , C:Choice ,AC:Action)

Q:Hi is there anyway that i can help you?

A:You own me 5 dollars!

C1:Ask politely to return them to you, C2:Τhreaten her , C3:Draw your gun

A1:No way get out of here , A2:Call the security , A3:Call the cops

AC1-2:Exit the building  //end of choices 1-2

C3.1:Draw your gun and shoot the cops , C3.2:Jump from the window

AC3.1:Arrested , AC3.2:Dead

Comment: Ehm what is the question in terms of code ? Do you have written any code so far ? What have you researched so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your game is going to have little dialogue, I would use `String`s for it, but if you base it around the dialogues, I would use a SQLite or similar database to store them in it. I don't know whether it will be the most efficient way to do that, but that what's occurred to me while reading your question:

[image]

You could use e.g. column 1 for the question, and columns 2, 3, 4, 5 for the possible answers. You can get information about using SQLite in libGDX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826805/how-to-use-sqlite-with-libgdx)

You could make into some method actor, whom he pass an id to access the SQLite for the question and the answers to that question, then assign some variables, and use a switch statement, if you don't want to have much if-elseif etc.

**Note:** I think that SQLite is mostly used when you want data to be saved and used in the future; if the data for example change every 10 minutes, I think it would be better to use JSON, because in SQLite making connections to the database every 10 minutes may take some time. I think this is not the case; in my opinion the purpose of JSON and SQLite is completely different. I would use for example:

**JSON** = I would use it to send or/and receive data betwen server & client or configuration files etc.

**SQLite** = I would use it to store data.

This is only my opinion, and I not say that SQLite is better or worse than JSON.

PS 1: the photo is taken from the Internet

PS 2: I also believe that you should read https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: while I agree with the fact that Paul's comment is inappropriate because it's not constructive - the proper way to respond to such comment is simply to flag them (e.g. as not constructive), not to edit your answer to point to a *particular* person. I've reworded Your answer (with some grammar fixes along the way), hope You don't mind.

Comment: @vaxquis thanks for your correction, i look you "inappropriately", I'm sorry if I bother you,